# Custom URL's to users, dynamically at a scale

Tags: url-rewriting, url-routing, custom-url

I need to create custom urls for my users, for ex: www.example.com/alpha, www.example.com/beta. I was creating symlinked directories, which I think worked as a good starting point for prototyping. However, now I need to do this at a scale, running on several web servers behind a load balancer. I am not sure on the right way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running on an Apache server and you have access to .htaccess files then try this in a .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ index.php?p=$1
```

This will point all URL's to index.php?p=* internally.
A user will see the .html, and the server interprets it as the pointed url.
Example: yourdomain.com/cocacola.html -> yourdomain.com/index.php?p=cocacola

Comment: Thanks for the accepted question :) Hope your project goes well!